# When would a viewport not be rectangular

Tags: html, css, viewport

In terms of web design, Mozilla's MDN defines [*viewport*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/viewport) as follows:

> A viewport represents a polygonal (normally rectangular) area in computer graphics that is currently being viewed. (clipped for brevity)

It mentions "normally rectangular" in this definition, which makes me wonder: in what case would an HTML viewport **not** be rectangular?

Comment: I assume in future cases it might be non-rectangular, so the MDN definition covers that.

Comment: When Apple will release the circular iPhone. The iPhone CX

Comment: I just remembered this: https://youtu.be/yZBVnjXp7GQ. Unleash the power of the Pyramid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretical cases aside: When the website is being [viewed on a recent iPhone](https://booking.design/how-we-adapted-the-booking-com-mobile-site-for-the-iphone-x-notch-e880fa00e989) or other [phone with a notch](https://www.cnet.com/pictures/phones-with-notches/).

[image: iPhone X]

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot about that!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what others have commented, I have determined that this definition is future-proofing for when viewports might not be rectangular.

Comment: Watch faces are commonly circular, and those exist today!

Comment: "future-proofing"? Non-rectangular viewports entered the mainstream last year.

Answer (score -1):

Another example is the Moto 360 screen, which was circular. In [this video](https://youtu.be/Xt9aznX9x0I?t=458) there is an actual use of the circular viewport